# C# Service not running infinite times

Tags: c#

I have a c# Service, that performs a database renewal. every hour. I have uploaded it in the server. I adjusted it to seconds, it works a few times, and then does not work again. It also works if i press it a single time.
How do i make it work every hour, for ever? (until i make it stop).

I tried changing the loop to i <100000, and it had no difference.

Code:
 program.cs

```
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
             {
"insert database"
}  } ,null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

main.cs

```
static void Main()
        {
            Service1 myService = new Service1();
            myService.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

            // 0, ,0, 10 seconds. adjust accordingly.
            TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(interval);
            }
```

Comment: 1/; make a program that make one run. Lunch it every hour with Scheduled Task?

Comment: You should either use the Windows' Task Scheduler or a scheduler library like Quartz.NET.

Comment: 2/. Make a Win Service..

Comment: Uhh...change `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` to `while (true)`? Really though, this is what the Task Scheduler is for.

Comment: Please start with something simpler than a Service ...

Comment: And this is not how you lunch a service.. you install it via command line and set to auto if you want them to be always here.

Comment: Or with a `ServiceController`.

Comment: 1-Why is my question downvoted? Sorry for not being an expert.
-2: How do I install a service via the command line then?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because your question about why it only works 5 times instead of forever is insanely obvious. There's a loop that iterates 5 times. Not a huge mystery there.

Comment: Sorry, adding:
I tried changing the loop to i <100000, and it had no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to System.Timers.Timer instead of Threading.Timer

You can then call the start of the timer when it finishes.

```
static System.Timers.Timer timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(periodTimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}

private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do some stuff

    timer.Start();
}
```

Or you can add `timer.AutoReset = true;` so it just keeps running instead of starting it yourself, I restart it manually so I can have it run at 9am, 12am, 3pm and 6pm exactly, no matter when the service is actually started by changing the interval.

Answer (score 0):

You should be writing a windows service.

Follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Then install your service using the following in the command prompt:

`sc create <servicename> binpath= "<pathtobinaryexecutable>" [option1] [option2] [optionN]`

Set your service to auto if you want it to run continuously.

Use the option flags to change parameters in your service (ie. change the interval, etc).